# All queries with WHERE user_id = "" have slow performance

Tags: mysql, performance

My website begin to work slow and after checking my phpMyAdmin, I see that all the queries in my `show processlist` are associated to my users table (`gebruikers`)

[image]

my user table has 64k rows with many fields.

[image]

Any ideas how I can improve the performance of this table?

Comment: `EXPLAIN SELECT` on those queries - are they using idexes? Also, are you using INNODB or MyISAM? The "waiting for table level lock" is suspect - are you perhaps running an `UPDATE` or have an abandoned `TRANSACTION` that is locking the table?

Comment: Create index over the USER_ID field : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/create-index.html

Comment: Update: You have one query `UPDATE ...` which is locking the whole table. Looks like MyISAM, which doesn't support low level locks. This lock is blocking all your other queries on that table. Further, the update has two fields in the `WHERE` clause - if these fields are not indexed, then this update will take a very long time causing major issues - which you are seeing.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE gebruikers` -- it will show the indexes and engine.

Comment: [_Tips on converting to InnoDB_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/converting-tables-from-myisam-to-innodb/) , which seems to be needed.